# How to use ng-repeat inside a directive template Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem displaying the JSON object data that my controller passes to the directive template. Here's my code.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('heroes', function(){
    return{
        scope:{
            heroes: '='
        },
        template: '<li ng-repeat="x in hereos">{{ x.Name }} </li>', // DOESNT WORK
        link:function(scope,element,attributes){

            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getData = function(){
          $http({
              url: 'js/directives/herolist.php',
              method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data) { $scope.heroes = data.records; })

    }
```

Comment: maybe you shoul try $scope.$apply() in $http callback

Comment: what does $apply do? you mean $http.$apply ??

Comment: @scokmen $http will triggers the $digest

Comment: Guess `ng-repeat="x in hereos">` is a typo btw? (Hereos instead of heroes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xksCEn8ecYvd33HJ64g?p=preview)

You should include the directive in your HTML and rename your values a bit

html can be

```
 <heroes data="heroes"></heroes>
```

then in your directive you would do

```
 scope:{
        heroes: '=data' 
    }
```

If you would do heroes: "=" and you are not restricting the directive to let's say an element, then you are basically including the directive twice (you don't want that). If you do want to use heroes as an attribute, like this

`<heroes heroes="heroes"></heroes>`

then add

> restrict: "E"

to your directive.

Comment: yep. still the same can't display

Comment: Thanks! this worked.. just a question.. <heroes data="heroes"></heroes> do I always need to post a "="heroes" inside the scope of a directive? what does it mean by the way?

Comment: In this case yes. You are passing the data from your controller to the directive. In your controller you have $scope.heroes = data.records; if that would be $scope.myData then you would do  <heroes data="myData"></heroes>. The directive has its own scope and in the directive you can define attributes to easily pass data (see : scope:{
        heroes: '=data' 
    }). That is where you link the value of the data attribute of your directive to the scope of your directive. Hope that makes it a bit more clear for you. I recommend you to read a bit more on directives to get a clear understanding.

Comment: Thanks muller! yes I am watching videos on directives right now. And it so happen I just stumble upon '=<somevariable>' in your answer. I thought it was just imited to '=', '@' . But anyways thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for this plunkr, saved my life